# Water heater T/P line dripping on side of house?

Tags: water, heater

Overflow pipe from water heater was leaking on side of house. Was told I needed new water heater and expansion tank. Both replaced as well as a new PRV on main line. Still getting a constant drip in line. They replaced the new T/P valve on new heater just to be sure and it still drips. They suspect something else tied into line but it’s in finished ceiling. What would be tied into it that is constantly dripping?  How can I diagnose?

Comment: Anything above the floor close by that might have a drain/drip line?  AC, dehumidifier,some coffee makers(question last week).

Comment: Shut the water heater off (just the heat source, not the water inlet). Drain a gallon or so of hot water at any sink in the house. Leave it for a few hours. Does it still drip? If yes, then it's probably not coming form the water heater.

Comment: If your ceiling is just painted drywall, repairing damage from exploratory surgery isn't nearly as bad as if it's plaster & lath or if it has a plaster skim coat. It might be the only way.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Shawn. Please [merge your accounts](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Note that posting responses as answers can result in an [automated lock](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) that can prevent others from assisting you.